# C++ string returning as "

Tags: c++, string, reverse, function-definition

I am trying to write a function that reverses a string. I've figured out most of the code, and when I print the string to `std::cout`, it's showing what I need. But, when I test the code, the result is that I got `"` from the function. Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 
string result;
string reverseString (string str)
{
  for(int i = str.length(); i >= -1; i--) {
    result+= str[i];
  }
  cout << result;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: That isn't a runnable program by itself. Please show a *complete* example. We can't tell you what's wrong with the code unless we see how you use it.

Comment: That said: do you understand the difference between a local variable and a global variable? Which kind is `result`? Why have you chosen that way?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 
While I haven't dived in to scope in C++. I am well aware of the differences of a global variable and a local variable(at least in C#). I chose to make result a global variable since I tried with a local variable and it didn't work. Also, this is actually a question on codewars, I could add in the tests they show.

Comment: `string reverseString (string const& str) { return string(str.rbegin(), str.rend()); }`

Comment: Or, you can simply do away with this manual function and use the standard [`std::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) algorithm instead, eg: `string str = ...; std::reserve(str.begin(), str.end());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this `for` loop, in the very first iteration:

```
  for(int i = str.length(); i >= -1; i--) {
    result+= str[i];
  }
```

The terminating zero character `'\0'` is being written in the first position of the object `result`, because the expression `str[i]` is equivalent in this case to the expression `str[str.length()]`.

So, the `result` string is outputted as an empty string.

Also, you are trying to access the source string using the negative index `-1`, which results in undefined behavior.

Instead of this `for` loop, you could just write:

```
result.assign( str.rbegin(), str.rend() );
```

If you want to do the task using the `for` loop, then the loop can look like the following:

```
result.clear();
result.reserve( str.length() ); 

for ( auto i = str.length(); i != 0; ) {
    result += str[--i];
}
```

Pay attention to that, it is a bad idea to use the global variable `result` within the function. The function could look like:

```
std::string reverseString( const std::string &str )
{
    return { str.rbegin(), str.rend() };
}
```